# Anyone experiencing intermittent Submit fail and redirect to CP dashboard/home? (ee 2.7.2)

Tags: control-panel, error, database-error

On several different installs I'm finding that when I finish editing an entry and hit **Submit**, the submission **sometimes** completely fails and I am redirected to the Control Panel home page.

I'd like to stress that in all cases I **remain in a logged in state** so it seems to be a different issue than the OP was raising in the EllisLab forum thread at [How to stop CP timeouts completely](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/238571/#1060289) – although I note that some of the commenters in that thread are citing the same behaviour as I am describing here.

I have 3 different installs where this is happening, each with a different mix of add-ons from lots and lots to effectively none.

At first I thought it was to do with the security warning interjecting on a 2.6.1 install, but now that is updated and yet it's still happening.

And just now, it's happened to me while working on a **local** 2.7.2 install in which the only add-on installed is Wygwam. But Wygwam is currently not being used on any fields, so the active number of add-ons on the entry that just failed to submit is zero.

That said, as I'm concluding that I probably don't need Wygwam at all on that install I shall disable it and see if this weirdness happens again.

Anyone else got this kind of thing going on? Because it's not good and it's understandably bugging my clients on the live installs.

Comment: Just happened to me again when updating a field *after* uninstalling Wygwam, so with *no add-ons*.

Comment: Happens to me in 2.6.1, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an XID issue/bug that is known to EL and slated to be corrected in the next release. A fix until then is posted:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19920#12050

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on all my recent installs. Here is a thread that may help you. I just found this, and will be trying the couple things they recommend:

[Save issue: Submitting entry edits redirects to control panel top?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/352/save-issue-submitting-entry-edits-redirects-to-control-panel-top)

Comment: Thanks Adam. Yeah, I'd seen that some weeks ago when this issue first started emerging for me, and I noted that that thread is nearly a year old and so the latest EE that could have applied then was 2.5.3 which I never had any such problems with. I've only noticed this from 2.6.1 onwards.

Comment: Furthermore, that thread is very much focused on add-ons which didn't really help me with 2 add-on dependent installs. What irks me is it just happening to me this morning on an install in which (almost) no active add-ons apply.